# validation failed at Path is required, react, node and mongoose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I don't why this failed validation from the mongoose backend when I try to send the post request from the frontend, but if I test my backend API request with postman, it's working fine.

> Feedback validation failed: receiver: Path `receiver` is required.,
> classCodes: Path `classCodes` is required., level: Path `level` is
> required., content: Path `content` is required.

> controller for my backend API

```
exports.createFeedback = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log('data from frontend', req.body);
    const feedback = await new FeedbackSchema({
      receiver: req.body.receiver,
      teacher: req.userId,
      classCodes: req.body.classCodes,
      level: req.body.level,
      content: req.body.content,
      send: req.body.send,
    }).save();

    return res.json({ feedback, message: 'Feedback Created' });
    } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.json('Failed to create feedback!');
  }
};
```

> Feedback Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const FeedbackSchema = new Schema({
  receiver: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true,
  },
  teacher: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  level: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Level',
    required: true,
  },
  classCodes: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'ClassCode',
    required: true,
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 300,
  },
  note: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 300,
  },
createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
});

module.exports = {
  FeedbackSchema: mongoose.model('Feedback', FeedbackSchema),
};
```

if I send a request from the postman is works fine without validation failed, but if I tried to send a request from the frontend, I receive a validation failed at Path above.

***Note: don't border about the ratings schema***

For frontend request. As you can see I log all the data before send it to the backend, `content, level, receiver and classCodes` and I also try to `console.log(req.body)` in the backend as well and I receive those data as well but still it show validation failed at Path is required.

> Backend log

[image: backend log]

> Frontend log

[image: frontend log]

> Postman request worked fine

[image: post api request is working fine]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the data nested in a `values` property, try to change your code like this:

```
exports.createFeedback = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { receiver, teacher, classCodes, level, content, send } = req.body.values;
      const feedback = await new FeedbackSchema({
        receiver,
        teacher,
        classCodes,
        level,
        content,
        send,
      }).save();
  
      return res.json({ feedback, message: 'Feedback Created' });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      res.json('Failed to create feedback!');
    }
  };
```

Comment: You are correct. Thank you for your response. Have a nice day